wp_verify_nonce for comment form is not returning false
Nonce creation; for testing purposes with 30 seconds:
//function to generate nonce field
function noncelife(){ return 30; }
add_action( 'run_custom_nonce_value', 'custom_nonce_value' );
    function custom_nonce_value(){
    add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );
    $created_nonce = wp_nonce_field( 'creacomments', 'creacomment_nonce');
    remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );
    return $created_nonce;
}

successfully adding nonce fields to the comment form:
//Add fields after default fields
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'additional_fields' );
    function additional_fields () {
    custom_nonce_value();
    }

verifying:
//verification
add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', 'crea_verify_comment_nonce' );
function crea_verify_comment_nonce() {
    add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' ) ;
    wp_verify_nonce( 'creacomment_nonce', 'creacomments' );
    remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );
        if (!$crea_nonce){
            print "Erreur";
            //exit; //uncommented shows white screen with 'Erreur'
        }
    }

With 30 seconds, i would expect the verification to fail, when submitting a comment after the time has elapsed and print: 'erreur';. This is not happening. Instead the comment is displayed. When i uncomment exit; a white screen appears showing 'Erreur'. Is 'pre_comment_on_post' the right action hook? How can i make this verification work and show a custom message?

Instead of adding the nonce_life filter and then immediately removing it, try telling WordPress that the lifetime for your nonce is 30 seconds.
add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'wpse426626_my_nonce_lifetime', 10, 2 );
/**
 * Sets the nonce lifetime for the creacomments nonce.
 *
 * @param  int    $lifetime The nonce lifetime.
 * @param  string $action   The nonce action.
 * @return int              The filtered nonce lifetime.
 */
function wpse426626_my_nonce_lifetime( $lifetime, $action ) {
    if ( 'creacomments' === $action ) {
        // Sets the creacomments lifetime to 30 seconds.
        $lifetime = 30;
    }
    return $lifetime;
}

Then use the nonce as you already are.

Thanks. I added your filter and removed the ones i previously used. After the time has elapsed, it is not returning false.

I checked your filter in another context than comments, and it works alright and simplifies the code. But as i said, this does not solve my validation problem. thanks
